# color changing text on button click

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, button

I have two buttons in windows forms. Let's say the text on one button is "WORD". When that button is clicked, I want the color of the text to change in this order: red, green, blue. I only want it to stop changing colors when the other button is pressed. What would be the best way to acomplish this?

I don't have much code, but this is what I have:

```
        private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
```

Comment: Use an eventhandler for the button click and a timer to swith the colors

Comment: For sure there are few ways how to achive it. Could you provide some code samples what you did already?

Comment: Google: C# winforms change colour of button. By the change you mean on every click? Add an array and counter. Stop changing? Add a boolean flag to prevent changes?

Comment: @Michel: that's a good start; now add a timer. You can change the color in the timer_ellapsed method

Comment: @Stefan `Timer.Tick`, otherwise you'll have to explain later how to marshal to the UI Thread (really not needed here).

Answer (score 0):

Use an the EventHandler with the Button.click event and an if-clause

- mybutton.click += ...